# OrientDb graph TRAVERSE between two vertex with conditions

Tags: java, sql, graph, orientdb, graph-traversal

This is my graph schema (little part):

[image]

`BusStation` is class which extends `V` (Vertex).
Every `BusStation` element has `stationId` property with some value (1,2,3,4,5...).

`Bus` is class which extends `E` (Edge). 
Every `Bus` element has three properties:

- `busId` : Id of bus between two station (Long)
- `departure` : time when bus went from station (Datetime)
- `arrival` : time when bus came on next station (Datetime)

I want to find `$path` from `BusStation` with `stationId = 1` to `BusStation` with `stationId = 5`.
When I execute this query through editor/Java code:

```
SELECT $path as path FROM (TRAVERSE outE(Bus), inV(BusStation) FROM select * from BusStation where stationId = 1 strategy BREADTH_FIRST) WHERE @rid == #17:3509
```

I will get shortest path, but I have some conditions which I must follow:

- First I want to be on same bus as longer is posible. This means that if I get on `stationId = 1` `Bus` with `busId = 1` on `stationId = 2` I want also get `busId = 1`, on `stationId = 3` so on, and on `stationId = 4` because I don't have `busId = 1` I will pick one of possible ability.
- Second is filter on arrival time of one bus and departure bus to another bus. I must watch out that if some bus arrive on station in 09:00, I must pick from that BusStation buses which have departure time after that arrive time (09:00).

Do you have some idea how thru query I can filter this conditions?

Comment: Hi, on the path from station 1 to station 2 the departure is set to 10:00 and the arrival to 9:00, is it correct or did you accidentally swapped them? THX in advance

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Hi Michela, yes, it is my mistake, sorry. I create databese from Java code and Maven dependency said: `<orientdb.version>2.2.12</orientdb.version>`

Comment: I don't know if you can do what you want with a query using traverse, I think you could use a javascript function

Comment: Thanks Alessandro, I tried to avoid function (Javascript/Groovy) because I little be afraid performance issues. My data set is huge. Do you have some experience  with performance of graph function?